# Tensorflow 2.2 not respecting thread settings (inter_op, intra_op, and OMP_NUM_THREADS)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I am running a tensorflow application that sets inter_op, intra_op and OMP_NUM_THREADS, however, it completely ignores these settings and seems to run with the defaults. Here's how I'm setting them:

```
import tensorflow as tf
    print('Using Thread Parallelism: {} NUM_INTRA_THREADS, {} NUM_INTER_THREADS, {} OMP_NUM_THREADS'.format(os.environ['NUM_INTRA_THREADS'], os.environ['NUM_INTER_THREADS'], os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS']))
    session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=int(os.environ['NUM_INTER_THREADS']),
        intra_op_parallelism_threads=int(os.environ['NUM_INTRA_THREADS']))
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

I have validated that it's reading the right values (the print prints the values as expected). I have also tried with other Tensorflow 2 versions with no success.

I am at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Version Info:
tensorflow                2.2.0                    py37_2    intel
tensorflow-base           2.2.0                         0    intel
tensorflow-estimator      2.2.0              pyh208ff02_0

keras                     2.4.3                         0
keras-base                2.4.3                      py_0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1

Comment: I have also tried hardcoding the values to 1, with no success....

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout the new way of using TensorFlow v2, as they eventually gave up `tf.session` and started to do ["Functions, not sessions"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2#functions_not_sessions) (you may realise you should probably use the v2 functions by looking at the function name `tf.compat.v1.xxxx`).

There are four threading related config setting functions for you ([documentation here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/)):

- `get_inter_op_parallelism_threads()`: Get number of threads used for parallelism between independent operations.
- `get_intra_op_parallelism_threads()`: Get number of threads used within an individual op for parallelism.
- `set_inter_op_parallelism_threads()`: Set number of threads used for parallelism between independent operations.
- `set_intra_op_parallelism_threads()`: Set number of threads used within an individual op for parallelism.

So the solution is to simply use the following code at the beginning of your code:

```py
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(4)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(16)
```